# Speed up table filtering in Matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, dataframe

Let `A` be a table in Matlab. Is there a **quick** way of accessing subsets of this table? Say all entries for which a certain column contains numbers in a range or such. The problem is that `A` is very large and I evaluate `A(A.col1 == i,:)` very often.

I then use the following simplified code to

```
B = zeros(1,N);
for i=1:N
     temp = A(A.col1 == i,:);      % this line is evaluated often and takes a lot of time since A is big table
     B(i) = FancyFunction(temp);
end
```

So, is there a **quick** alternative to `A(A.col1 == i,:)` or `A(ismember(A.col1,x),:)`?

Comment: @LuisMendo If ``x`` is just one number, is ``A(A.col1 == x,:)`` faster/better than ``A(ismember(A.col1,x),:)``?

Comment: Probably faster, yes; and it looks cleaner. I assumed you meant `A(ismember(A.col1,x),:)` applied to the whole range of values `x`

Comment: Yeah, definitely faster. `ismember` has significant per-call overhead compared to a plain `==` operation. So if `x` is scalar, use `==` instead of `ismember`. But if `x` is a nonscalar array, you gotta use `ismember`.

Comment: Oh, one possible complication: is `A.col1` a numeric column, or a `string` or object array? If that's the case, you might be able to speed this up by doing a one-time conversion of the column to numeric proxy keys, and then doing your comparisons in the numeric domain. But if `A.col1` is already numeric, there'd be no win there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you're doing it right.

`A(some_logical_index,:)` is the conventional, and AFAIK fastest, way to subset rows of a `table`. `A.col1 == i` produces a logical index, and since you're applying a function separately to each of those groups, it's reasonable to do that one-at-a-time. Or if your groups are based on a set of keys, `ismember(A.col1, x)`, where `x` is a possibly-nonscalar array, is the conventional and probably the fastest way to do it, and also produces a logical index.

There's also the `groupsummary` function provided by Matlab, which is a "vectorized" version of this loop you're doing: it groups the table by column values, and applies a supplied function to the groups to produce an output. This could be a more concise way of expressing what you're doing here. *In theory*, this could be faster, because it could be accelerated by Matlab using its internal threading. But in practice, in my testing, `groupsummary` only performs as fast as a regular M-code loop over the groups. Might be something you want to do in case Matlab accelerates this in the future, but you won't see any win right now (as of Matlab R2019b).

If your table contains homogeneous columns - either all numeric or all strings or all objects of the same class - you may be able to speed this up by converting your table to a plain matrix of type numeric, cell, or string. This would avoid the `table` class overhead.

You may be able to get a minor speedup by "projecting away" any columns in `A` that are not actually used in the `FancyFunction` calculation: subset the array `A` columnwise to just the columns that are required by `FancyFunction`; that way you're not paying the time & memory to subset any of the unneeded columns.

Comment: Thank you, I am already ''projecting away'' unneeded columns but from your answer, I got the impression that matlab can work faster with matrices than with tables and I ought to change my table to a matrix? All entries in the table are numeric. So, would ``A(some_logical_index,:)`` need less take time when ``A`` is an array rather than a table?